# iPhone: UIImage as background of UITableCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

What is the best way to place an image as the background of an UITableCell?  I was thinking of using the cell.contentView property, but it won't compile.

Is there a preferred method of doing this?  And maybe an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are using `UIImageView` and then having its `image` property set to the `UIImage` you want. also, contentView is not the property you want, you want the `UITableViewCell`s `backgroundView`

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `-[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:` for this purpose.